# Attempting to create a new HubExchange App - Linking account is causing a redirect loop

Tags: marketing-cloud

I've used 3 different browsers (not that it should matter) and each time I'm stuck in a redirect loop when attempting to link my ExactTarget account with the HubExchange App on step 2 of the new HubExchange App wizard.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you try logging in to your Marketing Cloud account beforehand and then click the link button.

Comment: The same thing happens. I am able to log on to Marketing Cloud without issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is typically your session has expired on Code@ and AppCenter.  Log out of Code@, log back in, and try from there. Let me know if that fixes it.

Comment: Tried this, still getting the redirect loop.

Comment: Here's a screencap of Fiddler showing the redirect loop:

http://imgur.com/nlCl6mF

Comment: Looks like this is specific to the S6 environment, and I have a couple engineers looking into it.  I'll let you know what I find out.

Comment: Try opening a private browsing session, and see if maybe there are cookie issues.  If so, then clear your cache and go from there.  I use private browsing so I don't have to kill my cache all the time.

Comment: Same results when using incognito browsing in chrome.

Please keep me updated.

Comment: Hmm, whats your account MID?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12876/discussion-between-nathanc-and-kelly-j-andrews)